# Retrieve values from NSDictionary (which is stored in a NS Mutable Array) from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

i've stored colors in a dictionary which is added to a nsmutable array.i want to retrieve values of the dictionary from another class based on the keys.thanks in advance

```
-(NSMutableArray *) GetAllColor 
{
    UIColor *aminocolor1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:.09 green:.56 blue:.30 alpha:.1];
    UIColor *aminocolor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:.1];

    NSDictionary *colordict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              aminocolor1, @"1",
                              aminocolor2, @"2",
                              nil];

    NSMutableArray *colors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:colordict, nil];
    return colors;
}
```

Comment: too little info and what you are trying to do

Comment: Are you asking also about how to call this function from a class ? Than paste us the class you are using. Basically it will be just [yourClass GetAllColor]; called on it's instance (after you alloc init it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just chain messages:

```
NSDictionary* colorDict = [colors objectAtIndex:0];
UIColor *aminocolor = [colorDict objectForKey:@"1"];
```

Or the same in one line:

```
UIColor *aminocolor = [[colors objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"1"];
```

Comment: @grzegorz but how to retrieve from another class.can u please tel me the format. i am new to the iphone

Comment: @Daij-Djan sorry - it is an answer + I gave two option so he can choose. Don't know what are you complaining about.

Comment: BUT dont do it on the same line and dont advice it IMO

Comment: @Daij-Djan I think it depends :) sometimes I prefer one line to not create local variables just to use them once - that creates a lot of unnecessary overhead - especially if you're doing it in loop.

Comment: yes, I agree that in some cases it might be good but generellay I avoid it

Comment: why not `UIColor *aminocolor = colors[0][@"1"];`

Answer (score 0):

Seeing this piece of code, I have to ask, why do you add the `NSDictionary` into an `NSArray` ? Why don't you just return the `NSDictionary`?

Now the simplest solution:

If you want to get all the `NSDictionary` from `NSArray` (if you have more then 1)

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in colors) {
   //do whatever you want with the dictionary (now it's the dict that has the collors)
   [dict objectForKey:@"1"] // this is how you get animcolor1.
}
```

If you want to get just a dictionary at a certain index:

```
if([colors count] > 0 && [colors count] < yourIndex) { //be smart and perform validations ;)
     NSDictionary *dict =  [colors objectAtIndex:yourIndex];
    //do whatever you want with the dictionary (now it's the dict that has the collors)
    [dict objectForKey:@"1"] // this is how you get animcolor1.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare that array as a globally to use that array in some other class.